# Optimizing DynamoDB Read Consumption

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have table which has a `String` column of date. the sample input is `2018-12-31T23:59:59.999Z`. It is not indexed.

Now what would be better from `Read Capacity Consumption` if I want to fetch all records which are older than a given date.

1. Should I scan the whole table and apply logic in my script **OR**
2. Should I use DynamoDB condition while scanning the records.

What I mean to ask, is RCU computer based on what results are being sent or is it computed at the query level. If its computed on results then option 2 is an optimized approach but if it is not then it doesn't matter.

What do you guys suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The RCU is based on the volume of data that was accessed in disk by the Dynamodb engine, not the volume of data returned to the caller. Using DynamoDB conditions you will get the answer fast because that probably will be a lot less bytes to be sent to network, but it will cost you the same in terms of Read Capacity Units.